# How to reflect web app hosted on EC2 (AWS) on mobile app (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, rest, amazon-web-services

So my current task at the company I'm interning with is to create a mobile version (iOS) of a web app written using Flask, HTML & CSS that currently exists and is being hosted on AWS's EC2. Assume I'm a complete noob at AWS and only just learned that EC2 is a cloud computing service.

Essentially, I just want to be able to reflect what's currently on EC2 over to a mobile app in a secure fashion. I guess I'm just trying to avoid rebuilding something in Swift that's already been done. For those familiar with WebView in Xcode, I tried to use that to reflect the web page, but it didn't work (I assume because our web app on EC2 requires login credentials when you open it in a browser?).

I thought that maybe using AWS's SDK for iOS would net me some luck, so I installed cocoapods and setup a pod, but don't know how or which of these AWS services will help me achieve what I'm trying to do (from reading the documentation, it seems like their purpose is for building an app, not necessarily just projecting a webpage with data already in it).

For some more information, some key features that I think would be useful for our clients that would be using the app are:

1. The ability to persist data on the app when their device is offline
2. Some sort of temporary logins for the users. This app wouldn't be distributed through the app store; it would probably just have to be locally downloaded onto certain clients' devices

Lastly, I saw this post come up before creating this one: [Does REST API for mobile apps hosted on https protocol web app will be slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35101884/does-rest-api-for-mobile-apps-hosted-on-https-protocol-web-app-will-be-slow) and I noticed that the asker of this question said "Lets say I have built a mobile app running on Android and iOS platform and REST API's for these apps lie under https based web application." This possibly sounds like something that could be helpful, and if anyone could explain what s/he meant by REST API's and what they are, I would be very grateful.

Any advice on how to proceed from here, using anything, would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think explaining that other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35101884/710041) you linked doesn't warrant an answer, so I'll just let you know here. I don't think it'll help you, since it was basically initiating a discussion on whether the added encryption in HTTPS over HTTP will make apps relying on REST interfaces slow. As you can see it's now closed for that reason. It seems you are not familiar with REST or maybe don't even know what it is, so to be honest your task might be a little hard for you atm. I don't have much time right now but will try to check here again tomorrow.

Comment: @Gero Thanks for the comments. That's true, I'm not familiar with REST, but do you think that it's something that will be necessary in the construction of this app? Because I, of course, would be willing to learn more about it in an attempt to complete this.

Comment: That depends on what the app should do and how the existing app works. It sounds like the web app you're supposed to port uses a REST interface (AWS), but it might be sufficient for you to just load the page in a webview (which might still work, even though you're tried). As I said, my time is a little short atm. I'd suggest reading up on [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) in any way. I guess it would be best to discuss this in a chat instead of comments here. There is not an easy answer, sorry.